# How can I use this in a one-shot for The Esoterrorists?

Tags: adventure-writing, gumshoe, one-shot, the-esoterrorists

> [Ehud Netzer, the Israeli archaeologist
>   credited with discovering the tomb of
>   the biblical King Herod, has died
>   after falling during a dig.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-11655704)

What spin can make this a great adventure for *The Esoterrorists* RPG. What is the entry point? What would be the core clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Netzer has uncovered evidence about a previous incarnation of the OV. It appears that Herod was part of this organisation and he ordered the Massacre of the Innocents to cover up what was seen as a breach in the veil. That there are no sources on this other than the Bible is proof of the power of his veil out. Netzer never talked widely about his work and was writing up his thesis in his private notebook (by hand, being old school) but enough leaked out into academia that the OV had the local branch keep tabs on him. Lately they have been worried that Netzer was about to publish and stepped up their efforts to get hold of his research. One member of the dig was an OV informant, although they thought they were giving the information to a dispensationalist Christian group (such as Hal Lindsey's). She managed to get hold of Netzer's notebook in the confusion surrounding his death.

However Netzer also drew the attention of some esoterrorists, keen to prove and promote the link between Christianity and the Outer Dark. They had been attempting to summon entities to carry off Netzer and deliver his work. Unfortunately when Netzer died and the informant got the notebook, this caused the entity, which looks a bit like a biblical angel, to carry of the informant. The entity, which was not fully formed when summoned, has fed off the informant's belief and thinks it is an angel. Together they have set up a new religious movement in the desert. The local OV cell tried to intervene but have been converted to the new religion by the shining radiance of the entity and the Esoterrorists are struggling to regain control of their entity. A few of them have been overcome too.

1. Disappearance of local OV cell leads to information about informant
2. Informant's family and friends aware of disappearance and one knows that she is in the desert but is embarrassed to say so.
3. Some of the new religion, an ex-OV cell and ex-Esoterrorist, return to city to evangelise. They know where to go in the desert. They also talk of the glory of the shining radiance which opened their hearts (i.e. don't look at it!).
4. Show down in the desert between entity, converts, Esoterrorists and PCs.

Answer (score 2):

The objectivity/subjectivity realm was penetrated, not in large scope, but in miniature. Netzer fell during a dig because of a seizure. The seizure was because a subjective-realm entity finally finished objectifying inside a tiny corner of Netzer's brain. The entity was held in Herod's tomb, but was greatly diminished by age and therefore inhaled as a dust mote.

The entry point is Netzer asking the OV to join him in his hospital room. He's had dreams that Herod is returning. He's seized by an Esoterror cult and they are attempting to use him to reenact the butcheries of King Herod.

Core clues are:

- Scene 1, the hospital room: an fMRI of his brain (there's something off about [medical jargon])
- Scene 2, King Herod's tomb: purple dust in the etchings, the remains of an objectified demon, cysts now.
- Scene 3, A small town hospital: various forensic evidence after a king herod like outbreak

And then it develops into a standard plot.